How does a scalar field's quartic interaction affect the Yukawa potential it generates for another field?
A common example field theory is one with a spinor $\psi$ and a real scalar $\phi$:
$$L=i\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi-m_\psi\bar\psi\psi+\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi-\frac{1}{2}m_\phi^2\phi^2-g\phi\bar\psi\psi$$
The scalar field mediates a force between 'psions', the excitations of the spinor field, with a Yukawa potential:
$$V=-\frac{g^2}{r}e^{-m_\phi r}$$
Now if we add a quartic interaction to the scalar field:
$$L'=L-\frac{1}{4}\lambda\phi^4$$
How does this change the force that the scalar field creates between the psions? Does it make the force stronger or weaker?

The Yukawa potential is computed from the 4-point-tree level diagram of four fermions exchanging a scalar. I would suppose that if we include a 4-vertex all scalar interaction $\lambda\phi^4$, then this would only contribute at loop level of the form 0 modulo the fermion legs. That would just be the 1PI of $\lambda\phi^4$-theory. You could take that result, perform a particular limit, and see if you can find the potential.
